# How do I hide a view when listview is scrolled up and show view when listview is scrolled down

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I used ItemAppearing and ItemDisappearing events but it is not working as per my requirement (it is working fine in iOS but not in android) and I created custom render for listview for listview scroll I failed to do that. Can anyone please help me out.

```
private void scheduleservicelist_itemappearing(object sender, xamarin.forms.itemvisibilityeventargs e)
{ 
    var currentitem = e.item as mymodel;

    if (viewmodel.mylistlist[0].id == currentitem.id)
    {
    headerlayout.isvisible = true; headinggrid.margin = new thickness(0,-70, 0, 0);
    }
}

private void scheduleservicelist_itemdisappearing(object sender, itemvisibilityeventargs e)
{
    var currentitem = e.item as mymodel;

    if (viewmodel.mylistlist[0].id == currentitem.id)
    {
        headerlayout.isvisible = false; headinggrid.margin = new thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

private void ScheduleServiceListView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    double scrollposition = e.ScrollY; if (scrollposition > previousScrollposition)
    {
        isScrollUp = true; isScrollDown = false;
    }
    else if(scrollposition < previousScrollposition) 
    {
        isScrollDown => true; isScrollUp = false; 
    } 
    else  
    { 
        if (isScrollUp) 
        {
            isScrollUp =true; isScrollDown = false;
        }
        else
        { 
            isScrollDown = true; isScrollUp = false; 
        } 

        scrollposition = 0;
    }

    if (isScrollUp )
    { 
        HeaderLayout.IsVisible = false;
        HeadingGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        HeadingGrid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
    }
    else 
    {
        HeaderLayout.IsVisible = true;
        HeadingGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, -70, 0, 0);
    }
    previousScrollposition = scrollposition;
}
```

Comment: If you are just trying to show and hide a header when the first item appears on the screen, you could try listview header.

Comment: I tried Listview header but the itemdisappearing event is not firing when I use Listview header